# Shrink/Remove dual boot partition Windows XP(or 7)/ RHEL

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp, partitioning, multi-boot

A colleague has a dual boot laptop with Windows XP or 7 (not sure yet) on one partition and RHEL 5.8 on the second. The RHEL partition is rarely used and the windows partition will soon reach its quota. My colleague has asked if I can shrink or remove the linux partition. As it is not my machine I am quite wary about this as I do not want to inadvertently lose data/system settings that are not my own though I have asked my colleague to backup all essential data on an external hard drive beforehand.

What are my options and what are the pitfalls in this process.

I assume it will be best to configure the partition settings from the linux side but I am not sure how to go about this tast safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is easy and painless to perform, provided you follow three simple rules.

The first rule is "Back up your data". The second rule is "Back up your data". The third rule is "Back up your data". I kid you not.

The simplest way to proceed is to use a Linux live distribution, like Ubuntu's. You download to your pc the installation iso file for Ubuntu, you put it onto a USB stick (you can use a utility called unetbootin which exists in both Windows and Linux versions), boot from the USB stick, choose the option "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu", open a terminal, issue the commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted
 sudo gparted
```

and select the disk to be re-partitioned. Now you can you select the operations as you see fit (resize the Linux partition, first, then resize the Windows partition), and when you are done you give the command "Apply selected operations" or some such thing. If you prefer to remove the RHEL partition altogether, you can simply delete it, leave it empty, and then let the Windows partition grow into the free region adjoining it (the former RHEL partition).

Then you wait for a substantial amount of time (depending on the partition size, might even last several hours), until gparted has worked its magic.

Now you are nearly done, except that most likely your system won't boot. If you have erased the RHEL partition this is certain, because you have removed the partiton containing grub, which controlled the booting process. In this case you will have to use the Windows installation disk to boot from, and then select "Repair installation", and the disk will take it from here. If instead you have decided to keep the RHEL partition, you proceed as follows: from the ubuntu terminal, mount the partition containing the RHEL system,

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

where X is the appropriate number for the RHEL partition. Now do this:

```
 sudo chroot /mnt
 sudo update-grub
 exit
```

Turn off the pc, and you are done. But please, remember the three Golden Rules of partitioning which I wrote at the beginning.